# javascript blur focus Infinity loop

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
         window.onload = function(){
             
         var input = document.getElementById("test");
         input.addEventListener("blur",function(){
            if(confirm("confirm")){
                alert("true.");
            }else{
                alert("false.");
                input.focus();
            }
         });
         }
    </script>
```

I solved it was "input.focus()" deleted.
But I want to use "input.focus()".
Why is it infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `alert` will trigger blur after you call `input.focus` again.

You'd better set a timeout to avoid that:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var input = document.getElementById("test");
    input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        if (confirm("confirm")) {
            alert("true.");
        } else {
            alert("false.");
            setTimeout(function(){
              input.focus();
            }, 10)
            
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="test" />
```